# highlight current page in rails 3 by id

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, uinavigationbar, background-color, highlight

I am rendering my main top navigation in a loop in Rails 3:

```
<ul>
<% Placement.all.each do |placement| %>
  <li><%= link_to placement.placementname, placement_path(placement.id)%> </li>
<%end%>
</ul>
```

How can I highlight the background of the current placement based on the id in the url? the url looks like this:
localhost:3000/placements/1
localhost:3000/placements/2
...

Once the user clicks on one of those tabs a second navigation bar will appear on the left side. This is how I am rendering it:

```
<% @placement.ads.all.each do |ad| %>
    <li><%= link_to ad.adname, placement_ad_path(@placement, ad) %> </li>
<%end%>
```

How can I highlight the background of the current ad based on the id in the url? the url looks like this:  localhost:3000/placements/1/ads/1
localhost:3000/placements/2/ads/3
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul>
 <% Placement.all.each do |placement| %>
   <li class=<%= "highlighted" if placement.id==params[:id].to_i %>>
       <%= link_to placement.placementname, placement_path(placement.id)%> </li>
 <%end%>
</ul>
```

and

```
<% @placement.ads.all.each do |ad| %>
  <li class=<%= "highlighted" if ad.id==params[:id].to_i %>>
    <%= link_to ad.adname, placement_ad_path(@placement, ad) %> </li>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. What exactly is ".to_i" ? it wouldn't work without it.

Comment: Actually one issue once I navigate on ad and the url changes to 'placement/1/ad/5' the placement.id is taking 5 instead of 1. then i replaced your code with placement.id==params[:placement_id] but it only works when I'm in the show.html.erb of ads (palcement/1/ads/4) but it wouldn work in the show view of placement (placement/1) since in the placement show it needs to look for params[:id] and not params[:placement_id]. do you know how to fix that?

Comment: ah, solved it this way:   <% if params[:controller] == "placements" %>
  <ul>
  <% Placement.all.each do |placement| %>
    <li class=<%= "highlightedTopNav" if placement.id==params[:id].to_i %>> <%= link_to placement.placementname, placement_path(placement.id)%> </li>
  <%end%>
  </ul>

<%else%>

  <ul>
  <% Placement.all.each do |placement| %>
    <li class=<%= "highlightedTopNav" if placement.id==params[:placement_id].to_i %>> <%= link_to placement.placementname, placement_path(placement.id)%> </li>
  <%end%>
  </ul>
<%end%>

Answer (score 0):

Use stylesheets and selective application of class names. Presuming that you've already set `@placement` and `@ad` in your controller, I'd do something like this:

```
<ul class="placements">
<% Placement.all.each do |placement| %>
    <li class="placement <%= 'selected' if placement == @placement %>">
        <%= link_to placement.name, placement %>
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>

<ul class="ads">
<% @placement.ads.each do |ad| %>
    <li class="ad <%= 'selected' if ad == @ad %>">
        <%= link_to ad.name, [@placement, ad] %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

Then you can put something like this into your stylesheet. (Here I'm assuming SCSS or LESS.)

```
.placements {
    .placement {
        // Normal styling goes here

        &.selected {
            // Extra styles for selected items go here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the params hash to retrieve ids, compare them and attach a css class to the lis:

```
<ul>
<% Placement.all.each do |placement| %>
  <li class="<%= 'highlighted' if placement.id==params[:id] %>"><%= link_to placement.placementname, placement_path(placement.id)%> </li>
<%end%>
</ul>
```

and

```
<% @placement.ads.all.each do |ad| %>
    <li class="<%= 'highlighted' if ad.id==params[:id] %>"><%= link_to ad.adname, placement_ad_path(@placement, ad) %> </li>
<%end%>
```

Then in your stylesheet declare the CSS class :

```
.highlighted{ background-color: #f00;} /* Whatever color fits your needs */
```

Comment: Thanks Jef. I literally copy pasted your answer but nothing changed, not even an error! I just did a test to see if it really drops 'highlighted' in the class with running this code:   

    <ul>   
    <% Placement.all.each do |placement| %>   
    <li><%= 'highlighted' if placement.id==params[:id] %></li>     
    <%end%>   
    </ul>

But the result in my browser is empty, does not show the letter highlighted. Do you know why? the url i am testing it on is localhost:3000/placements/1